# Two column per subject in categorical data- histogram

Tags: python, pandas, plot, histogram

```
    Gene1      Gene2        Gene3 ..... Gene123
1   variant    reference    variant     variant
2   reference  variant      variant     reference
3   reference  reference    variant     reference
4   ....       ...          ...         ...
5   ...        ...          ...         ...
..
..
90  reference  variant      variant      reference
```

I have a datest with a certain number of participants and 123 genetic columns.
I'd like to create an histogram that shows for each person, the number of "variant" and "reference" he/she has for EACH gene.
So I expect something like an histogram where each participant has 2 columns: one displaying the number of "reference" and the other displaying the number of "variant" he/she has.
How can I do?

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it making use of [`pd.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) (I used made up sample data with three genes and four participants to demonstrate):

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'g1': ['v', 'v', 'v', 'r'],
    'g2': ['v', 'r', 'v', 'r'],
    'g3': ['r', 'v', 'r', 'v']
})

counts = df.reset_index().melt('index')
pd.crosstab(counts['index'],counts.value).plot.bar()
```

And here's what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Ok but since I have hundreds of rows and columns, is there any faster way to put my data  into the code? So that I don't have to add every list one by one

Comment: There's no need to manually input anything. Just use your dataframe instead of my sample df. The last two lines should give you the plot